# Percurso em níveis na árvore binária

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

Estou tentando criar uma função que percorre uma árvore binária em níveis através de uma fila encadeada, mas quando compilo mostra a mensagem de erro "Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)".

```
//Estrutura da árvore
typedef struct no{
    int chave; 
    struct no* esq;
    struct no* dir;
}NO;

typedef struct arvore{
    NO* pont;
}ARVORE;

//Estrutura da fila
typedef struct elemento{
    NO* reg;
    struct elemento* prox;
}ELEMENTO;

typedef struct fila{
    ELEMENTO* head;
}FILA;

void criaFila(FILA* fila){
    fila->head = NULL;
} 

void insereFila(FILA* fila, NO* p){
    ELEMENTO* novo = (ELEMENTO *) malloc(sizeof(ELEMENTO));
    novo->reg = p;
    novo->prox = NULL;
    if(fila->head==NULL){
        fila->head = novo;
    }else{
        ELEMENTO* pointer = fila->head;
        ELEMENTO* ant = NULL;
        while(pointer!=NULL){
            ant = pointer;
            pointer = pointer->prox;
        }
        ant->prox = novo;
        free(pointer);
    }
}

NO* removeFila(FILA* fila){
    if(fila->head!=NULL){
        ELEMENTO* pointer = fila->head;
        fila->head = pointer->prox;
        return pointer->reg;
    }
}

int tamanhoFila(FILA* fila){
    ELEMENTO* pointer = fila->head;
    int tam;
    while(pointer!=NULL){
        tam++;
        pointer = pointer->prox;
    }
    return tam;
}
void percurso(NO* raiz){
    FILA fila;   
    NO* prox;
    criaFila(&fila);
    insereFila(&fila, raiz);
    while(tamanhoFila(&fila)>0){
        prox = removeFila(&fila);
        printf("%d ", prox->chave);
        if(prox->esq!=NULL){
            insereFila(&fila, prox->esq);
        }
        if(prox->dir!=NULL){
            insereFila(&fila, prox->dir);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "falha de segmentação" ocorre na execução do programa, não na compilação!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás a inicializar a variável tam sem nenhum valor, tens de lhe atribuir um valor antes de a chamares no ciclo while.

```
//Estrutura da árvore
typedef struct no{
    int chave; 
    struct no* esq;
    struct no* dir;
}NO;

typedef struct arvore{
    NO* pont;
}ARVORE;

//Estrutura da fila
typedef struct elemento{
    NO* reg;
    struct elemento* prox;
}ELEMENTO;

typedef struct fila{
    ELEMENTO* head;
}FILA;

void criaFila(FILA* fila){
    fila->head = NULL;
} 

void insereFila(FILA* fila, NO* p){
    ELEMENTO* novo = (ELEMENTO *) malloc(sizeof(ELEMENTO));
    novo->reg = p;
    novo->prox = NULL;
    if(fila->head==NULL){
        fila->head = novo;
    }else{
        ELEMENTO* pointer = fila->head;
        ELEMENTO* ant = NULL;
        while(pointer!=NULL){
            ant = pointer;
            pointer = pointer->prox;
        }
        ant->prox = novo;
        free(pointer);
    }
}

NO* removeFila(FILA* fila){
    if(fila->head!=NULL){
        ELEMENTO* pointer = fila->head;
        fila->head = pointer->prox;
        return pointer->reg;
    }
}

int tamanhoFila(FILA* fila){
    ELEMENTO* pointer = fila->head;
    int tam;
    tam=0;
    while(pointer!=NULL){
        tam++;
        pointer = pointer->prox;
    }
    return tam;
}
void percurso(NO* raiz){
    FILA fila;   
    NO* prox;
    criaFila(&fila);
    insereFila(&fila, raiz);
    while(tamanhoFila(&fila)>0){
        prox = removeFila(&fila);
        printf("%d ", prox->chave);
        if(prox->esq!=NULL){
            insereFila(&fila, prox->esq);
        }
        if(prox->dir!=NULL){
            insereFila(&fila, prox->dir);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Verdade, foi falta de atenção! atribui zero a variável e funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda.